# PHP: $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] not found

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP at the moment, and I'm having a small problem related to PHP and HTTP authentication.

I'm testing out storing users and passwords in a MySQL database, and creating a login form to authenticate a user. I can get the form to display, but when I enter a username and password (that I know are in the database) and hit "ok", I the window just keeps resetting itself and re-displaying with blank input boxes.

I think I've tracked down the problem to the $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] not being set by the popup auth window when I send data, and the first "if" statement not executing. Does anyone know why this may be?

Here's a snippet from my code:

```
  <?php 

require_once 'login.php';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to mySql: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
echo "Databse selected<br/>";

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
{
    echo "Auth found<br/>";
    $un_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $pw_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un_temp'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
    elseif (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $salt1 = "qm&h*";
        $salt2 = "pg!@";
        $token = md5("$salt1$password$salt2");

        if($token == $row[3]) echo "$row[0] $row[1] : hi $row[0], you are now logged in as '$row[2]'";
        else die("Invalid username/password combo");
    }
}
    else 
    {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo("Authing<br/>");
        die("Please enter your username and password");
    }
```

Comment: Depending on several factors, the credentials do not necessarily have to be passed under those two parameter names. Do a `var_dump($_SERVER)` to see if they are passed under different parameter names (you’ll have to do that after you send the headers and before exiting the script with `die`).

Comment: If you are learning php you should go straight to PDO or mysqli and dump the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.